# iPhone load Htmlstring in a UIWebView and replace text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have one html file like this one.

```
<body class="iphone" onLoad="doSomething()">
    <div id="title_wrapper"><h2 id="title">[[[TITOLO]]]</h2></div>
    <h2 id="subtitle">[[[DATA]]]</h2>
    <div id="content">
        [[[TESTO]]]
    </div>
```

I load it into my UIWebView and I want to replace the "[[[TESTO]]]" with the content of one NSString Variable.
How can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you have to do it in javascript?

To do it in Objective-C, just go:

```
NSString *templateHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"Filename" encoding:NSUTF8Encoding error:NULL];
NSString *finalHTML = [templateHTML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[[TEST0]]" withString:variable];
```

That will get you the HTML with your variable instead of [[TEST0]], which you can then load into your UIWebView using `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`.

Comment: Wow great! I'll try it tonight and than if I have no doubt I'll mark your solution as best. Thanks so much!

Comment: And If I want to call the method doSomething() how can I do??? <body class="iphone" onLoad="doSomething()">

Comment: If you load the page in the web view, it will run doSomething() automatically on load, exactly the same as if it was run in a browser.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `UIWebView`'s `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method to modify your HTML once it has been loaded:

```
NSString *title = @"New Title";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = %@", title]];
```

Comment: I tried this solution but the text is not being replaced in the HTML content. What can be the issue or cause for this?

Comment: Make sure you have single quotes around the placeholder, e.g. ...innerHTML = '%@'

Answer (score 1):

I did something like that before, but I did it in objective C.

just first build your html file

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body class="iphone" onLoad="doSomething()"><div id="title_wrapper"><h2 id="title">%@</h2></div><h2 id="subtitle">%@</h2><div id="content">%@</div>", titolo ,data, content];
```

and afterwards load it into the webview like this

```
[webView loadHTMLString:myHtml];
```